# Starting Wiley Template

Tags: errors, miktex, templates

I have downloaded the `Wiley Book Style` template, moved the complete file to my latex folder, then extracted the zip. Upon trying to generate a PDF, using MiKTEX, for `w-bksamp.tex` I return the error `wileySev.cls` not found.

In short, what is the sequence of operations needed to use the `Wiley Book Style` template?

Comment: Try putting `wileySev.cls` in the same directory as your document. Does that work?

Comment: Was it installed in the correct place? Did you refresh the `FNDB` with `MiKTeX Setting`?

Comment: As for every `.cls` or `.sty` it must be in a directory where TeX can locate them. In your case it wolud be `/[user]/AppData/Roaming/MikTeX/[version]/tex/latex/<wiley>`.

Comment: @Ruben this is how I stored the file, and why I mentioned that I moved the file to my latex folder. Sorry, if this wasn't made explicit. Nonetheless, I am still getting the same error when I try `w-bksamp.tex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the current MiKTeX 2.9, ecact from log file: `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.7.29)`.

BTW: Which version do you use? It could be that your version is a little bit outdated?! Have a look at the beginning of your log file and add it to your question.

If I copy the content of the zip file to a directory `WileyBook`, I can read and write (for example for user test on windows 7: `C:\Users\Test\Documents\WileyBook`) documents I can compile the file `w-bksamp.tex` without any errors or warnings, resulting in a pdf with 52 pages.  `C:\Users\Test\Documents` is the standard directory user `Test` of a windows computer can read and write with no restrictions ... 
Please keep in mind: both files, the class file and your thesis must be in the same directory (if not MikTeX will not find the class file and that is the error message you got).

If you want to have the class in a separate folder please follow question [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) to create a local texfm tree and follow question [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) how to install the class for Wiley Books. Please be careful: you need to refresh FNDB or it will not work because MiKTeX uses the FNDB (File Name Data Base) to locate class files in the texmf tree (system or local)!